# How to add users in SharePoint 2013 site in cloud account?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

I am new to SharePoint 2013, and I am now trying to learn about SharePoint 2013 by myself . I created my site in SharePoint 2013 in cloud service using Office 365. After I created my site, I need to add users and create group for my site. How do I add users like other mail id's? I went to Site Permission, and it is asking to invite people to 'Full control', etc. But in that column, if I give any other new mail id it does not accept it.

**How do I populate the members mail id, or how do I access or create members mail id in my site?** Then only I can invite people to access permission for my site.

I cannot access other mail id in my site. How do I create other mail id and populate that in textbox while giving permission? I am trying all of this in Cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is you can:

Add users to the People Service.

[image: People Service]

Use Office Directory Service

[Read about Directory Integration Services & SharePoint Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-sharepoint-online-user-profiles-from-the-sharepoint-admin-center-HA102772733.aspx?CTT=1)

Those users will  be validated in the text box you mentioned above.